# Cant resolve View Holder in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am new to RecyclerView and I want to implenet that but problem is I cant resolve viewholder reference in following code please help me out

```
class ViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
     override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewAdapter.ViewHolder {
        // return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.slider, parent, false))
    // }
     }

     override fun getItemCount(): Int {
         TODO("not implemented") 
     }

     override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
         TODO("not implemented") 
     }


 }
```

[image: code screenshot]

Comment: `ViewHolder` is an abstract class, you have to provide your own implementation.

Comment: If you're using an IntelliJ based IDE, you can alt + enter on top of the view that's unresolved and create the class.  In this case, that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create one class `ViewHolder` inside your `ViewAdapter` class

SAMPLE CODE

```
class ViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewAdapter.ViewHolder {
        // return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.slider, parent, false))
        // }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not define ViewHolder class in ViewAdapter

Just define ViewHolder class in ViewAdapter

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ViewAdapter` is the class that you're creating, so `ViewAdapter.ViewHolder` is an inner class of it.

You need to create this inner class, like:

```
class ViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

   ...

   class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        ...
   }
}
```